# Таблица стилей для ie

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

Если  к странице нужно подключить дополнительную таблицу стилей для корректного отображения в ие, то в эту таблицу стилей помещаются только те свойства, для которых нужно задать другие значения или нужно скопировать в неё всю основную таблицу стилей и изменить нужные свойства?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Только те, которые нужно изменить.

Основная таблица ведь в любом случае подключается, так что свойства, которые остаются без изменения, будут видны, и не нужно их заново определять.

Answer (score 5):

Можно поместить только нужные свойства и переопределить у них нужные значения.
но помните, что подключать их надо последовательно.

т.е.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
<!--[if IE ]><link rel="stylesheet" href="ie.css" /> <![endif]-->
```

вот как то так...

Comment: ну вот, пока красивости наводил -- опередили)

Answer (score 2):

Скорее первое, если я правильно вас понял.

Вы подключаете основную таблицу стилей для всех браузеров. Следовательно к IE они тоже применяются. Потом подключаете таблицу стилей индивидуально для IE и перекрываете в ней то, что вам не нравиться.

У IE, безусловно много багов и он много чего не умеет. Но задумайтесь. Ведь помимо него есть и другие отсталые браузеры. Их огромное множество, скажем, на мобильных устройствах. Лечите стили не индивидуально для IE, а для всех, кто не умеет.

Я рекомендую вам посмотреть на [пуленепробиваемый шаблон](http://html5boilerplate.com/). Это заготовочка для начала проекта от гуру фронтэнд-разработки. Там во первых JS-ка modernizr, которая, позволяет определять, что умеет браузер, а что нет. Эта же JS-ка в себя включает HTML5shiv - затычка на HTML5 теги в старых ie. При помощи условных комментариев  более элегантно происходит распознование старых IE в шапке.

Будут вопросы по этому пуленепробиваемому шаблону - спрашивайте отдельным вопросом :).